# Getting 'Unauthorized' error message while using Upload Power BI Report task in Power BI Actions Extension Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-extensions, azure-pipelines-tasks

I want to use the Azure DevOps Extension 'Power BI Actions' for uploading a report from my Azure Repo to a Power BI Workspace. I have installed the Power BI Actions extensions on my DevOps organization.
I have also created a Service Principal on my Azure Tenant and generated a client secret for the same. The Service Principal has the permissions Tenant.ReadAll and Tenant.ReadWriteAll added but they havent been given Admin grant yet.

The Service Principal has been added as an admin to the necessary Power BI Workspace as well.

I have then created a service connection using the above Service Principal for authentication purposes as username/password method on Power BI Actions Extension does not support MFA.

My end goal is to build a CI/CD Pipeline. Currently the build pipeline works as I am able to push a .pbix file to a drop container as an artifact.

The Release pipeline which only has this one task currently fails giving me an 'Unauthorized' error message and says that the workspace does not exist. I have checked multiple times. Workspace name is correct.

Could this issue be because of the API Permissions not granted? If so am I using the right permissions? Or are there any others that are required.

The link to the extension is attached [here.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-power-bi-actions)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not related to azure devops and only with azure, power BI.

Just my guess, please make sure that you have [added the service principal to your workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal#step-4---add-the-service-principal-to-your-workspace).

**Also**,

> Service principal only supports some read-only admin APIs. To enable
> service principal support for read-only admin APIs, you have to enable
> the Power BI service admin settings in your tenant. For more
> information, see Enable service principal authentication for read-only
> admin APIs.

**So** you should [enable the Power BI service admin settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal#step-3---enable-the-power-bi-service-admin-settings).

**Besides**, you should note [these tips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal#considerations-and-limitations) and make sure that you did not break